# how to transfer app data from old phone to new one?

Tags: applications, samsung, data-transfer

There seems to be a lot of questions regarding this topic, but what I want to know is, how do I transfer the data from all of my apps (not just one or two specific ones) from my old phone to my new one? I transferred the apps using Samsung Smart Switch, but all it did was transfer the apps, not the data, so much of my game history and information in other apps is not on the new phone. This also includes my various ringtone and notification settings; they're all set to the default setting instead of what I had on my old phone. (The one exception that I noticed was ColorNote, where all of my note files were copied over. And, there are others like Viber, Facebook and Messenger, which have their own means to get everything across. But most of them, including pretty much all of my games didn't have anything transferred except the apps themselves.)

How do I get all of the app data and settings from the old phone to the new one? Is there a utility available that will automate this? (Note: I'm going from a Samsung Galaxy A50 to an A53.)

Comment: Most apps do not allow backup, I assume this is the reason Samsung Smart Switch failed for so many apps. The way Google recommends is via online GDrive backup https://support.google.com/android/answer/6193424

Comment: @Robert if an app does not allow backup, how should GDrive backup be a solution? That app should not be included there then either.